# How do I limit the height and width of an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working on a game and the images are sized right but for some reason it's making a lot of extra space that isn't needed, In other words, it allows you to scroll up and down and side to side and there is nothing there to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try using

```
max-width:;
max-height:;
```

this can limit the maximum width and height of the page even when you resize the window and also

```
min-width:;
min-height:;
```

which sets minimum width and height

```
overflow:hidden;
```

hides the elements text or any other things that goes out the parameter

Answer (score 1):

Without sufficient details or a link then the really simple lazy solution is:

```css
body { overflow:hidden }
```

Just scan through the document tree in developer tools on your browser and check sizes and margins.

Comment: No, please explain in the answer already. That what it's for. No need for two lazy solutions.